# Create a node Automatically when a commerce order is completed

Tags: hooks, rules, commerce

In my site, I am using drupal commerce in order to run  a shop.

In my plan, a new node must be created when an order is completed. (paid)

Also in new node creation I want to use the order's field values. (for example order id, or username (and uid ) who ordered , entity values & etc )

Please help me. How can I setup this solution?
can I do this process via "Rules" or I have to create a module and use hook functions?

Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: you should preferably create a custom code

Comment: you mean custom module programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its time to [create a module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7), and use these nice [hooks](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/DC) Commerce API is offering to interfere to the regular execution of things in your Drupal site.

After getting the big picture, creating a node will be as easy as [this](https://drupal.org/node/1388922) first script.
So in a hook which is invoked whenever an order is complete, you would add the node creation code.

Comment: yes, I am working on it. I will share my codes as soon as I can.

Comment: I am still working on it. Automatic node creation is completed when a new order is registered and paid. But I need to modify specific nodes when an order is modified. Can you tell me what is the hook name when a commerce order is modified by user?